# LINQ with dynamic where clause in EFCore

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I'm using net5.0 and EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.4.

I have a search method that has optional strings to search for on a DataContext in EFCore.

I want to check if each of the strings is not null or white space.

I could do this:

```
var query = context.Model.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameters.Id))
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.Id.ToLower().Contains(parameters.Id.ToLower()));
}
```

but that is just horrible to maintain. What I started trying to get going is this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string? searchValue,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> getValueExpression)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue?.Trim()))
    {
        return query;
    }

    // return with a where clause
}
```

I got this working but it does not support accessing joins that I need and I get the feeling this is not a good way:

```
var searchLower = searchValue.Trim().ToLower();
var propertyName = getValueExpression.GetMemberAccess().Name;
return query.Where(x => EF.Property<string?>(x!, propertyName)!.ToLower().Contains(searchLower));
```

I want to use it like so:

```
query                        
.FilterBy(parameters.Id, x => x.Id)
.FilterBy(parameters.Name, x => x.Name)
.FilterBy(parameters.CompanyName, x => x.Company.Name) // access via include/join
```

### Solution

```
    private static readonly MethodInfo StringContainsMethod =
        typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), new[] {typeof(string)})!;
    private static readonly MethodInfo StringToLowerMethod =
        typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.ToLower), Type.EmptyTypes)!;

    public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string? searchValue,
        Expression<Func<T, string?>> memberExpression)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
            return query;

        var valueExpression = Expression.Constant(searchValue.ToLower());
        var toLower = Expression.Call(memberExpression.Body, StringToLowerMethod);
        var call = Expression.Call(toLower, StringContainsMethod, valueExpression);
        var sourceParam = memberExpression.Parameters.First();
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, sourceParam);

        return query.Where(predicate);
    }
```

#### Integer

```
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int? filterInteger,
        Expression<Func<T, int?>> memberExpression)
    {
        if (filterInteger == null)
            return query;

        var valueExpression = Expression.Constant(filterInteger);
        var call = Expression.Equal(memberExpression.Body, valueExpression);
        var sourceParam = memberExpression.Parameters.First();
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, sourceParam);
        return query.Where(predicate);
    }
```

#### Boolean

```
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, bool? filterBoolean,
        Expression<Func<T, bool?>> memberExpression)
    {
        if (filterBoolean == null)
            return query;

        var valueExpression = Expression.Constant(filterBoolean);
        var call = Expression.Equal(memberExpression.Body, valueExpression);
        var sourceParam = memberExpression.Parameters.First();
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, sourceParam);
        return query.Where(predicate);
    }
```

Comment: The real problem is `x => x.Id.ToLower`. That prevents the server from using any indexes and is simply not needed in most databases as they use case-*in*sensitive collations. Besides, a Primary key isn't supposed to contain any business information like names so the case shouldn't matter, even when the ID is a string instead of eg an auto-generated integer

Comment: Besides, `x.Id.Contains(someParam)` results in a `LIKE '%abc%'` that can't use indexes either. What are you trying to do? Are you looking for full text search perhaps?

Comment: Finally, `x.Company.Name` accesses a related entity's property. It doesn't access anything via Join or Include (which isn't needed, since the navigation is already part of the query). That related entity may *not* be a standalone entity, but an owned type, stored in the same table as the rest of the entity.

Comment: I have several tables I want to be able to search for different fields, these can be string, integer etc. I don't want to mess around changing the schema that is shared by other services. I want to have a way of making these where clauses more easily than making DRY code.

Comment: By second-guessing the collation though, you're trying to Repeat what the server already does, resulting in serious if not critical performance issues. What you wrote will scan every row in a 1M-row table to find matches. And even `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue?.Trim())` is a bug - the method already checks for nulls or empty strings, so all `searchValue?.Trim()` does is leak temporary strings. Once you fix the problems you're left with `if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue){ query=query.Where(x=>x.Field.Contains(searchValue)); }`.

Comment: Besides, with an ID you'd **never** want to use `Contains`, only `==`. With text, 99.999% of the time you want `StartsWith` which translates to `LIKE 'abc%'` and *can* use indexes - that pattern is translated into a range query looking for all values starting with `abc`, something an index can handle easily

Comment: so when it boils down to it, how can use the property that I input to use StartsWith on and have my search string sent in? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this but I believe you'd need to use expressions to achieve this. The following will build an expression to use as the predicate in the Where method:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query, 
        string searchValue,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> memberExpression)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
            return query;

        // must be a lambda expression
        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = memberExpression as LambdaExpression;
        if (lambdaExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{memberExpression}' is not a lambda expression.");

        // get the member
        Func<ParameterExpression, Expression> sourceExpression = source => Expression.Invoke(lambdaExpression, source);
        ParameterExpression sourceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "source");
        Expression sourceMember = sourceExpression(sourceParameter);

        // expression for the search value
        ConstantExpression valueExpression = Expression.Constant(searchValue);

        // expression to call the Contains method
        MethodInfo containsMethod = GetContainsMethod();
        MethodCallExpression callExpression = Expression.Call(null, containsMethod, sourceMember, valueExpression);

        // predicate expression
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(callExpression, sourceParameter);

        return query.Where(predicate);
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetContainsMethod()
    {
        // get method
        MethodInfo genericContainsMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .First(m => m.Name == "Contains"
                     && m.IsGenericMethod
                     && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2);

        // apply generic types
        MethodInfo containsMethod = genericContainsMethod
            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(string) });

        return containsMethod;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks! This almost worked, and also threw me on the right trail.  I have updated with the solution which was a bit shorter :)